# If $f:A\to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous and one-to-one function, is $f$ strictly monotone?

Tags: functions, continuity, monotone-functions

> **Theorem (1):** Let $A \subseteq R$ be an interval and $f:A\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous one-to-one function.  Then $f$ is strictly monotone.
>
> **Theorem (2):** Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be an arbitrary set and $f:A\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous and one-to-one function.
> Then $f$ is strictly monotone.

Is Theorem (2) right?

Comment: No. Let $A=\{0,1,2\}$. Then every function on $A$ is continuous, but you can easily find $f$ which is not monotone on $A$.

Comment: So should $A$ be interval  ?

Comment: What do you mean "should"?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews . Necessarily=should

Comment: Still don't know what you mean. Ask a complete question, and I might be able to answer it. Help me help you.

Comment: What is the definition of "continuous function" that you are using? For example, $\frac{1}{x}$ is continuous on its domain $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ but is not continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

No. Suppose $A=[0,1)\cup(1,2]$ and define $f:A\to\mathbb R$ by
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x+1,& \textrm{if }x\in[0,1)\\
x-1,& \textrm{if }x\in(1,2]
\end{cases}
$$
The problem arises from the disconnectedness of $A$.